# Circle in D3.js only displaying text without circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw a circle using d3.js with text inside it.
Here is my code:

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles"></div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    circles();

    $(".circles").show();
    function circles() {
        var svg = d3.select(".circles");

        var groups = svg.selectAll("div")
            .data("DEMO")
            .enter()
            .append("div");

        groups.attr("transform","translate(" +100+ "," +100+ ")");

        var circles = groups.append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", "100")
                    .attr("cy","100")
                    .attr("r", "100")
                    .attr("fill", "red")
                    .attr("stroke-width","2.4192")
                    .attr("stroke","#00ffff");

        var label = groups.append("text")
            .text(function(d){
              return d;
            })
            .attr({
              "alignment-baseline": "middle",
              "text-anchor": "middle",
              "font-family":"Arial",
              "font-size":"30",
              "fill":"white"
            });
    }
});
</script>
```

But it displays only the text and the circle is not being displayed.
I am unable to fix it.
Can anyone please point out my  mistake and help me fix it.

Comment: try `style` instead of `attr` in `label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending a `<circle>` element in HTML, not SVG. It doesn't have any meaning there, so it doesn't get rendered. You need to append an svg element, then append your circle and text nodes to that.

Fill, stroke-width, and stroke should also be applied with `.style` instead of `.attr`.

Some relevant code changes are:

```
var svg = d3.select('.circles').append('svg') // added .append('svg')
    .attr('height', /* set the height */)
    .attr('width', /* set the width */);

var groups = svg.selectAll('g')               // 'g' instead of 'div'
    .data('DEMO')
    .enter().append('g');
```